# Node returns "[Function]" in command line

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I am new to NodeJS and my node.js code won't work, It only returns a "[Function]" as a result when i run `Node app.js`

```
//This is the index.js file

var  number, origin, destination;

exports.setNumber = function (num){
    number = num;
};

exports.setOrigin = function (o){
   origin = o;
};

exports.setDestination = function (d){
    destination = d;
};

exports.getInfo = function(){
    return{
        number     : number,
        origin    : origin,
        destination    : destination
    };
};

//This is the app.js file

var flight = require('./javascript_1')

flight.setNumber(356);
flight.setDestination('There');
flight.setOrigin('Here');

console.log(flight.getInfo);
```

Please help because I do not know what I am doing wrong here

Comment: getInfo is a function. You should invoke it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flight.getInfo` is a function. You must invoke it. Try replacing the last line with:

```
console.log(flight.getInfo());
```